# Remove second reference to object

Tags: c#, reference, factory

I got something like the following:

```
class Factory{
    private List<FactorizableObject> _collected; //Collection of all created objects

    public FactorizableObject createObject (someParams DontMatter){
        FactorizableObject newObject = new FactorizableObject(DontMatter);
        _collected.Add(newObject);
        return newObject;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithCollectedObjects(){
        //Work with created objects
    }
}

class UsingClass1{
    private FactorizableObject myObject;

    public UsingClass1(){
        myObject = Factory.createObject(someParams);
    }
}

class UsingClass2{
    private FactorizableObject myObject;

    public UsingClass2(){
        myObject = Factory.createObject(someOtherParams);
    }
}

class WorkingClass{
    List<UsingClass1> someOfThese;
    List<UsingClass2> someOfThose;

    private void triggerWork(){
        someOfThese.Remove(RemoveSomeObject);
        Factory.DoSomethingWithCollectedObjects();
    }

}
```

Now my Problem is: Even if I remove an instance of a usingClass from on of these lists, the entries in the factory still keep alive and get used when calling DoSomethingWithCollectedObjects. I expected something like a NullreferenceException when trying to work on the object.

The Question: Is there a way to kill the object (the reference to the object) without explicit removing it from the factory-collection? This would need to be done in any class using the factory, so I would like to get around this...

I need some collection like this to perform some special actions on the factorized objects and dont want to care where they are located (The action needs to be done on ALL of the objects). I already tried setting UsingClass1.myObject = null, before removing the object, but this only removed my reference onto the factorized object.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the 'IDisposable' interface? like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern

Comment: Hi, yes I tried this, too. But calling Dispose() on a UsingClass isnt removing the reference of the provider-collection onto the factorizableObject.

Comment: Its a little bit of a guess what your after, but i think you want to invalidate the reference in the list '_collected' from some other point? While i think you could do so theoretically by using WeakReferences (allowing the GC to collect the object when no other references exist) I believe there must be some usecase behind it that is better served with some other implementation...

Comment: You don't set an object to null, you set the reference to that object to null. Thus: if you have two variables towards the same object (references) and you set one to null, the object does not change and the other variable will still reference that object.

Comment: Can't you just create an event, or boolean property on FactorizableObject, set that with an method DoneWithThis() and handle the event, or inspect the property in the factory and removing the object from the list when needed.